# MySQL Master-Slave and slave as master - slave configuration

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

Currently I have normal MySQL Master - Slave configured. For ex :-
Server 1 as Master and Server 2 as Slave. 
Now I want Server 2 as Master (Which is already a slave for Server 1) and Server 3 as Slave.

I have setup replication between Server 2 as Master and server 3 as Slave. But the replication changes which happens on server 2 are not getting replicated on Server 3.

If I add a new table on Server 2 using Create table on Server 1 then it gets create on Server 2 but I want it to get created on Server 3 as well...... Is there any param which I need to set for this.

Please help.... I need to setup this kind of replication where whatever is getting replicated on Server 2 should get replicated to Server 3

Answer (score 4):

add --log-slave-updates to the Server2

Answer (score 0):

perform ddl commands seperatly on slave dbs and dont rely it. only rely on dml operations.

2nd option is re-configure slave again for slave 2.